# Spread operator solidity

Tags: solidity

is there an equivalent to javascript's spread operator in solidity?

I am hoping to do something like this

```
 struct Book {
      string name;
      string writer;
      string genre;
      string publisher;
   }
 
   string[] memory bookInfo = ["bookName", "bookAuthor", "bookGenre", "bookPublisher"];
   Book book1 = Book(...bookInfo);
```

Or is there a way to pass a struct to a constructor in solidity?

Comment: There's no spread operator on solidity. You can loop over the array and copy it's values (spend more gas) or just assign an array to another. You can even create a function that returns a memory array.

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent to JavaScript's spread operator in Solidity.

But you can initialize a struct the two following ways:

```
// Like a function
Book book1 = Book("book1Name", "book1Author", "book1Genre", "book1Publisher");

// Via a key-value mapping
Book book2 = Book({ name: "book2Name", writer: "book2Author", genre: "book2Genre", publisher: "book2Publisher" });
```

It is recommended to initialize it via a key-mapping for a better code clarity.

More examples here: https://solidity-by-example.org/structs/